# Reformatting of SQL Data for chart

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I need help with formatting the data from a sql query for creating charts.
This is the query below.

```
SELECT install_status, Date_appended , COUNT(serial_number)
FROM Asset_Base
Where  (Date_appended = '2017-09-26' OR Date_appended = '2017-08-31' OR Date_appended = '2017-07-31')
AND (install_status= 'Installed' 
OR (install_status= 'In Stock' AND u_install_sub_status = 'Available')
OR install_status= 'Missing') 
Group By install_status , Date_appended
```

Which returns :

```
install_status  Date_appended           (No column name)
In Stock        2017-08-31 00:00:00.000 10981
Installed       2017-08-31 00:00:00.000 58764
Missing         2017-08-31 00:00:00.000 51661
In Stock        2017-09-26 00:00:00.000 10830
Installed       2017-09-26 00:00:00.000 59083
Missing         2017-09-26 00:00:00.000 51209
```

Is there any way I can get the data to look like this instead?

```
Date_appended In Stock Installed Missing
2017-08-31    10981    58764     51661
2017-09-26    10830    59083     51209
```

Thanks!

Comment: There is, have a read of this one to do with Pivoting... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

If you just want one row per `Date_appended` just group by this:

```
  ...
GROUP BY appended;
```

If you want to have a column only counting `serial_numbers` where `install_status` is `In Stock` use the following:

```
SELECT
 COUNT(CASE WHEN install_status = 'In Stock' THEN 1 END),
 ...
```

The `case` expressions maps every non `In Stock` row to `null` (due to the implied `else null` clause of `case`). `count` generally ignores `null` values (like most aggregate functions).

The other columns can be added likewise.

Read more about this pivot technique here: http://modern-sql.com/use-case/pivot

Answer (score 0):

I think that you may use pivot. Hoping the below query is helpful for you :

```
       SELECT * FROM (
        select 'In Stock' as install_status, '2017-08-31' as Date_appended  , 10981 as 'serial_number'
        UNION ALL
        select 'Installed' as install_status, '2017-08-31' as Date_appended  , 58764 as 'serial_number'
        UNION ALL
        select 'Missing' as install_status, '2017-08-31' as Date_appended  , 51661 as 'serial_number'
        ) AS A
        PIVOT
        (
            MAX(serial_number)
            For install_status in ([In Stock] ,[Installed],[Missing])
        ) PT

RESULT : 
    Date_appended In Stock    Installed   Missing
    ------------- ----------- ----------- -----------
    2017-08-31    10981       58764       51661

    (1 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query.

```
SELECT * FROM 
    ( SELECT install_status, serial_number , Date_appended FROM @Asset_Base
      WHERE Date_appended IN ('2017-09-26', '2017-08-31', '2017-07-31')
            AND (install_status IN ( 'Installed' , 'Missing')
                OR (install_status= 'In Stock' AND u_install_sub_status = 'Available')) ) SRC 
        PIVOT ( COUNT(serial_number) FOR install_status IN ([In Stock], [Installed], [Missing])) PVT
```